# How to use Go's time package to format time like RFC3339, but without time zone (i.e. local time)

Tags: go

Right now I have an ugly way of getting an ISO 8601 local time string out of Go's `time` package (I need milliseconds significant figures).

```
t := time.Now()
now := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%f",
    t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(),
    t.Hour(), t.Minute(),
    float64(t.Second()) + float64(int(t.Nanosecond()/1E6))/1000)
fmt.Println(now)
```

I feel like this can't be the ideal way of doing this, but I can't find an example of a simple, inbuilt way of doing this. Does such a way exist?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000")`.

I'm assuming that the missing zero if the seconds is less than 10 was a mistake; if you really want that, then change `05` to `5`. If you want more or less digits after the decimal point, add or remove zeroes from the end of the format.

More on time formats [in the docs for the time package](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants).

Comment: I hadn't understood the significance of `To define your own format, write down what the reference time would look like formatted your way` in the docs. I really don't like that they've used a reference time; it just looks like a big magic number in the code.

Comment: @Escher on the other hand, when looking at a format, you know what the result is going to look like. I'd have gone for CLDR myself, but it's better than strftime at least. :)